# Does the Where clause inside PnP Powershell performed on the client or on SharePoint side

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell

I have this PnP PowerShell:-

```
$customerFolders= Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -PageSize 5000 -Fields "Id", "FileLeafRef", "Modified","FileDirRef","FileSystemObjectType" -Script {
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
    Write-Host "building CustomerFolders..." 
} 
 | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $mainfolderUrl -and $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
```

so how will this script work? will the script get all the data from SharePoint in batches of 5,000 and do the filtering on the client? or the filtering will be done on the SharePoint side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script will get all the items first, then do the fileter. In your case the cmdlet is like following

```
$customerFolders= $var | Where {$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $mainfolderUrl -and $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
```

$var is the collection of items. The script get all the items in $var then where clause start filter the data.

Comment: so how i can force the filtering to happen on the sharepoint side? so we do not have to get all items?